# Is it possible to modify existing properties of Location object like "location.href"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I just need to patch some properties of `window.location` object like `location.href` or `location.hash`. I don't sure that it's possible or not. I already try several ways but nothing works.

For example, if JavaScript code try to change value of `location.href` property, this monkey patching property should call `history.pushState` function instead. Logic should looks like the following code.

```
var customLocation = {
    set href(url){
        history.pushState(null, '', url);
    },
    set hash(url){
        history.pushState(null, '', url);
    }
};
```

Currently, there are 100 same-domain applications that are hosted in my web browser-like page. I try to handle any navigation of all applications with my code. Web browser should not know about it. I already patch `history.pushState` and `history.replaceState` functions. It works flawlessly.
[image]

PS. For most navigation in any context(iframe), browser always create new history entry to the top browsing context that allows user to navigate to previous state via  back button.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "patch some properties"?

Comment: @mherzig I just update my question.

Comment: Hmm. `href` and `hash` are handled by the browser so if they get set they change the actual page location, which would mean it tries to set the page location to your function. Which, even if it worked, is a new "page" and probably resets your overrides. Maybe someone else would have an idea, but I don't think it would be possible to completely override these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I quite confident that it cannot be done in normal browser because these properties are managed by browser itself.

The only possible solution is forcing any child applications to use `history.pushState` and `history.replaceState` instead because these native API can be patched and should work correctly when it runs outside my application container. As a result, I can fully manage history state of any child application.